# Are there plans to include pingback functionality in SE 2.0?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0, seo

The [pingback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback) protocol [specifies](http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback) a method for CMS software to alert another Web site that someone's posted something linking to the other Web site. This might have some value for SE sites -- there's some SEO value, but it's also a great way to automatically increase awareness of SE sites on topic-relevant blogs. Is this something that's ever been considered?

Comment: I would really like that, but prepare for posts saying "This isn't a blog/forum!"

Comment: I agree 100% -- part of the big education process over on RPG.SE is explaining that to people. But pingback isn't restricted to blogs -- it's just a way to notify people that a piece of content they wrote got a link from somewhere else, which I think is wholly within our scope.

Comment: So that's what that crazy "pingback" thing that I see every now and then is? It drives me nuts and I just mentally filter out those comments nowadays. Now I know what it's used for, but I'm not one who can really judge how useful it'll be.

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea. I think it may need clarification for those unfamiliar with it. If someone references a URL in a question, answer or comment, SE should contact the targetted web-site and inform it that StackOverflow is referencing it. The targetted site can ignore such notifications or display that reference however it likes. Blog software often treats it like a special sort of comment.

Comment: I note that at least one of the SE clones, that are (legally) reproducing SO questions is doing pingbacks, so they are getting references across many blogs.

Comment: I also support this idea. The main use would be that SE'd notify links that appear in the posts. This would raise awareness of SE, and in particular, it'd attract the authors of the linked blog posts to participate on SE questions that are relevant for them. Everybody would gain from it. But the reverse could be interesting as well. SE could be notified when people link its content and this information could be very useful to SE developers.